# $f(x)$ is a bounded function such that $\int_a^b(f(x))dx=0$ then does it imply that $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

The function that I have chosen is $f(x)=1, a \le x \le \frac{a+b}{2},and f(x)=-1 , \frac{a+b}{2} < x \le b  $.

The function is bounded and with only one point of discontinuity so it is Riemann integrable

Now, if we choose our partition to be $\{a,\frac{a+b}{2},b\}$ then we see that $U(P,f)=0 $ and $L(P,f)=0$.We know by the property of Riemann integration that if we choose any partition $Q$ on $[a, b]$ then $U(Q,f)\ge L(P,f)$ )I  can't  really  conclude  after this.

Comment: What conditions are there on $a$ and $b$? Does it have to be true for all $a,b$?

Comment: No $[a, b]$ is any interval which I can choose

Comment: It is a good idea to include the statement of your question in the body of the question and not rely on the title to tell us what you need help with. Here it is not very clear what you are asking: the answer to the question in the title is no and the example you give in the body demonstrates that (provided $a < b$). But the body reads as if you want help with proving why the integral is from first principles.

Comment: Any odd function over a symmetric interval will have a $0$ integral, without being the null function necessarily. You need more constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Take the function $$f(x)=sgn(x)$$ and take $a=-1 \ and \ b=1$. The integral is zero but the function is not itself zero over the range of integration.

Comment: Can you prove this with basic definitions that the integration  is $0$ this is what I am having a problem with.

Comment: @GuriaSona: so edit your question to make it clear what your problem is! Did you not read my comment on the question?

Comment: @GuriaSona: Your question is a bit unclear, do you want to ask if it is zero at one point or over the whole range?